The Google page with videos that one by one get played on tv stops after about 65 seconds using a Raspberry Pi
I am working on a kiosk presentation slide program on a raspberry pi, the slides work fine on a computer monitor, but when I try the program on a Television it resets to the first video after about 65 seconds. We have multiple raspberries but all have the same problem. The refresh rate and resolution are being set at 1920 x 1080 and 60 hertz.
The total duration of the presentation should be about 3 minutes but it consistanly cuts it off at 65 seconds, only on a TV while chromium is in kiosk mode. There is a program that runs on startup to launch chromium in kiosk mode set the right display resolution and refresh rate, and retrieve via an api call the url for the presentation.
I have tried multiple settings for chromium, playing the playlist url in the browser normally, that works fine. I ran it without kiosk mode, that resulted in the same with kiosk mode and the page refreshes.
If you have any tips, I would appreciate it!

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
